# how to make a roll the dice command with my discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

so basically ive tried alot of things and ive made a number swapper but cannot figure out how to randomize

```
    async def cmd_number(self, channel, player):
    """
    Usage:
        {command_prefix}number

    Displays a random number (useless but fuck it)
    """


    cards = ['1','2','3','4']
    hand = await self.send_message(channel, ' '.join(cards))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.6)

    for x in range(4):
        shuffle(cards)
        await self.safe_edit_message(hand, ' '.join(cards))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.6)
```

this is what my shuffle command looks like i just want a command that chooses a number 1-6 and says you rolled a 4! or 5! etc thanks for the help

Comment: As a heads up you should really att the programming language as a tag... otherwise your question will never be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Using the random module you don't need to shuffle to get a random number:

```
import random

cards = ['1','2','3','4']

await self.send_message(channel, "You chose number {}!".format(random.choice(cards)))
```

Comment: Your "answer" you posted isn't an "answer" and shouldn't  be there... Also, I can't really help when I don't exactly know the setup of your code? What are you passing to the class? Would help if you showed me the full code. @JeffBarger

Comment: I cant really show you the full code because its over 2k lines long but ill just drop this because its pointless anyway thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

i setup the code and it doesnt work, their is no error but this is what it looks like

```
    async def cmd_dice(self, channel, random):
    cards = ['1','2','3','4']
    await self.send_message(channel, "You chose number {}!".format(random.choice(cards)))
```

and i dide use import random because the (self, channel, random): chooses those modules

when i run the command it just give me the description

http://prntscr.com/fwcych

Answer (score 0):

This may work. I've used this for an 8ball command, but it should work if you want to roll a dice as well.

```
@client.command(name='8ball',
            description="Answers a yes/no question.",
            brief="Answers from the beyond.",
            aliases=['eight_ball', 'eightball', '8-ball'],
            pass_context=True)

async def eight_ball(context):
    possible_responses = [

        'That is a resounding no',
        'It is not looking likely',
        'Too hard to tell',
        'It is quite possible',
        'Definitely',
        'Maybe so.'

    ]
    await context.channel.send(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)
```